# PowerShell Как осуществить поиск по регулярным выражениям

Tags: регулярные-выражения, powershell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

К примеру нужно вытащить "bin\Release" из релизной конфигурации:

```
[xml]$proj = (Get-Content $projectFileName)

$nsmgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $proj.NameTable

$nsmgr.AddNamespace('a','http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003')

$assemblyName = $proj.SelectSingleNode('//a:AssemblyName', $nsmgr)

$node = $proj.SelectNodes("//a:PropertyGroup[@Condition]", $nsmgr)

$outputPath = $node| ? Condition -Like '*Release*' | select OutputPath
```

Можно ли как нибудь вытащить эту строку, только с помощью SelectNodes, что-то типо такого:

```
SelectNodes("//a:PropertyGroup[@Condition -Like '*Release*']", $nsmgr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно, XPath поддерживает функцию `contains()`:

```
SelectNodes("//a:PropertyGroup[contains(@Condition, 'Release')]/a:OutputPath", $nsmgr)
```